# C++ class exposed to QML error in fashion TypeError: Property '...' of object is not a function

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've successfully exposed a C++ class to QML. It is registered and found in Qt Creator. It's purpose is to connect to a database, as shown in following code:

```
#ifndef UESQLDATABASE_H
#define UESQLDATABASE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>

class UeSqlDatabase : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool m_ueConnected READ isConnected WRITE setConnected NOTIFY ueConnectedChanged)

private:
    bool m_ueConneted;

    inline void setConnected(const bool& ueConnected)
        { this->m_ueConneted=ueConnected; }

public:
    explicit UeSqlDatabase(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE inline const bool& isConnected() const
        { return this->m_ueConneted; }

    ~UeSqlDatabase();

signals:
    void ueConnectedChanged();

public slots:
    void ueConnectToDatabase (const QString& ueStrHost, const QString& ueStrDatabase,
                              const QString& ueStrUsername, const QString& ueStrPassword);
};

#endif // UESQLDATABASE_H
```

However, when I try to call method `isConnected()` from the following QML code

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle
{
    id: ueMenuButton

    property string ueText;

    width: 192
    height: 64
    radius: 8

    states: [
        State
        {
            name: "ueStateSelected"

            PropertyChanges
            {
                target: gradientStop1
                color: "#000000"
            }

            PropertyChanges
            {
                target: gradientStop2
                color: "#3fe400"
            }
        }
    ]

    gradient: Gradient
    {
        GradientStop
        {
            id: gradientStop1
            position: 0
            color: "#000000"
        }

        GradientStop
        {
            position: 0.741
            color: "#363636"
        }

        GradientStop
        {
            id: gradientStop2
            position: 1
            color: "#868686"
        }

    }

    border.color: "#ffffff"
    border.width: 2
    antialiasing: true

    Text
    {
        id: ueButtonText
        color: "#ffffff"
        text: qsTr(ueText)
        clip: false
        z: 0
        scale: 1
        rotation: 0
        font.strikeout: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.bold: true
        style: Text.Outline
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        font.pixelSize: 16
}

    MouseArea
    {
        id: ueClickArea

        antialiasing: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
            uePosDatabase.ueConnectToDatabase("127.0.0.1",
                                              "testDb",
                                              "testUser",
                                              "testPassword");
            if(uePosDatabase.isConnected()==true)
            {
                ueMenuButton.state="ueStateSelected";
            }
            else
            {
                ueMenuButton.state="base state"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> qrc:/UeMenuButton.qml:92: TypeError: Property 'isConnected' of object UeSqlDatabase(0x1772060) is not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have this error because you have declared the property `isConnected` in C++ but you're calling it from QML in the wrong way: `uePosDatabase.isConnected` is the correct way, not `uePosDatabase.isConnected()`.

If you want to call the function `isConnected()` you should change its name to differate it from the property, like `getIsConnected()`. Given your property declaration, you neither need to call this function directly nor you need to make it callable from `QML` with the `Q_INVOKABLE` macro.

Comment: I see this code: `Q_INVOKABLE inline const bool& isConnected()`, isn't Q_INVOKABLE expected to declare a method?

Answer (score 2):

You must first create the object you want in QML code and then use the function:

your QML Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QSqlDatabase 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: ueMenuButton

    QSqlDatabase {
        id: uePosDatabase
    }
.
.
.
    MouseArea
    {
        id: ueClickArea
        antialiasing: true
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked: {
            console.log(uePosDatabase.isConnected())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware in case of an error some lines earlier in the same .js file can lead to this problem. The following code will not be executed.